# how do I compare inputs from same methods in java

Tags: java

I would appreciate some assistance to show me where I went wrong. I am trying to compare fraction from the same method but I can't seem to get the output. there is no error when I run the code but there must be something missing hence I couldn't get the output.

I did try using setter and getter but it is probably not setting and getting the right thing

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    
    
    public void input() {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

        boolean flag=true;

        System.out.println("This program will display your input as fraction.");

        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("Enter a numerator: ");
            numerator = kb.nextInt();
            if (numerator < 0 ) {
                System.exit(numerator);
            }

            System.out.println("Enter a denominator: ");
            denominator = kb.nextInt();
            while (denominator == 0) {
                System.out.println("Plase enter a number other than 0: ");
                denominator = kb.nextInt();
            }
            if (denominator < 0) {
                numerator = ~(numerator - 1);
                denominator = ~(denominator - 1);
            }

            display();
            isZero(numerator);
            //setNumerator();
            //setDenominator();
        }
    }
    
    public void setNumerator(int numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }
    
    public void setDenominator(int denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
    
    public Integer getNumerator() {
        return this.numerator;
    }
    
    public Integer getDenominator() {
        return this.denominator;
    }
    
    public static boolean isZero(int numerator) {
        boolean fraction = false;
        if (numerator == 0) {
            fraction = true;
            System.out.println("Fraction is 0");
            System.exit(numerator);
        }
        return fraction;
    } 
    
    public void display() {

        if (numerator !=0) {
            System.out.println("The fraction is: " +numerator +"/" +denominator);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isEqual() {
        boolean equal = false;
        int otherNumerator = getNumerator();
        if (numerator == otherNumerator) {
            int otherDenominator = getDenominator();
            if (denominator == otherDenominator) {
                System.out.println("the fraction is the same.");
            }
            equal = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("the fraction is not the same.");
        }
        return equal;
    }
}
`

    
public class TestFraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fraction frac = new Fraction();
        
        frac.input();
        frac.display();
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Building and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you focus on what the actual problem is and will make it quicker for us to help you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff here that is misplaced. I don't think we can help with your specific issue right now because you will just get into trouble on the next line. You should rethink / rewrite the code completely:

- In the `main` you need to write the `input` logic. There should not be a `input` on `Fraction` itself, especially not as a non-`static` method.
- `display` should output something in case of `0` as well.
- `Fraction` should have a constructor that takes a `numerator` and `denominator`
- `isZero` is firstly basically useless and secondly it should ABSOLUTELY NOT call `System.exit()` and it should not be `static` at all.
- `isEqual` probably should take care of making `1/2` equal to `1/4`

Comment: hi luk2302, thank you so much for your input. I rewrote my code and managed to get the right output. thank you for the pointers. appreciate it so much.